# Stop Cygwin from pre-pending "c:\cygdrive' during windows batch command run

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin, cmd

Running a friend's batch file with this line

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=¶" %%i in ('which synplify_pro.exe') do set synplify_path=%%~dpi
```

the var synplify_path is getting set with c:\cygdrive pre-pended.

I just want the windows part.

Is there a way to prevent the pre-pend or get back just the windows part?

Comment: But if `c:\cygdrive` is part of the actual path where the file is located, then what is the point of removing it?

Comment: The next command in the batch file does not like the c:\cygdrive part. Not sure how to answer your reply.

Comment: Please run `which synplify_pro.exe` and report the full results. Also show the batch file that is failing, in particular the line that you say does not like c:\cygdrive part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could simply remove that part from the result.

If it is always there after the loop, you could simply cut it off like this:

```
SET synplify_path=%synplify_path:~11%
```

where `11` is the length of the string `c:\cygdrive`. If there's a `\` just after the offending string and it needs to be dropped too, make it `12`.

Alternatively you could do like this:

```
SET synplify_path=%synplify_path:c:\cygdrive=%
```

This will replace all the entries of `c:\cygdrive` in `%synplify_path%` with an empty string, i.e. it will simply remove that substring. This method may be better in case there's a chance that `c:\cygdrive` could be absent from the result for some reason: the method will leave the string unchanged if the string doesn't contain `c:\cygdrive`.

I'm not sure if you shouldn't actually try to resolve the issue with the command that doesn't like `c:\cygdrive` in the path, though...

Comment: +1, You hit every point I was thinking, but too lazy to write :)

Comment: Here is the whole section of code. ':: Check Synthesis version
if %use_synplify%==1 (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=¶" %%i in ('which synplify_pro.exe') do set synplify_path=%%~dpi
)
if %use_synplify%==1 (
    findstr /c:"%exp_syn_ver% README" "%synplify_path%\..\readme.txt" > NUL

    rem findstr /c:"%exp_syn_ver% README" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Synplicity\fpga_962\bin\..\readme.txt" > NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo.
        echo ERROR: Wrong Synplify Pro version detected!!!
        goto FAIL
    )
)

Comment: @Mikef: To be honest, I could see nothing in that section that `c:\cygdrive` in the path might offend. But if I still had my doubts, I would try running the script from the command prompt without turning ECHO OFF, to be able to see the particular line where the issue occurs. (I mean, not only to see *which* line but also to see the line itself after the variables' evaluation, to understand why things worked incorrectly.)

Comment: The issue with the code as written is that it manipulates a dir path with spaces (it finds a .exe under the x86 folder).  Cygwin does not handle this at all. Mike